# Perl Split Operator

Tags: perl

I have a large text file of records each beginning with 22-. I want to read in the file and split it up into an array with one record per element.  Looks like I will lose the 22- at the beginning of each element.  Is there a way to split it without losing the 22-?  I suppose after the split I could add the 22- back to the beginning of each element.

I haven't coded it yet

Comment: Please, read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If you haven't coded it yet, what makes you think you'll lose the `22-`?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for [the input record separator `$/`](https://perldoc.perl.org/variables/$/)

Answer (score 2):

With split, you specify the separator. `22-` is not a separator, but part of the record.

You can still use `split` by separating on the zero-width space that's followed by `22-`.

```perl
split /(?=22-)/
```